# compatible version of jackson-annotations to integrate with jackson-core-asl 1.8.5

Tags: jackson

I am using jackson-core-asl 1.8.5 to convert java pojo to Json. Now i want to create json with different attribute name . For that i have used jackson-annotations (@JsonProperty) but it didnt have any effect . It seems there might be some version problem. 
I cant able to find the correct version of jackson-annotations compatible with jackson-core-asl 1.8.5.

I cant able to change the version of jackson-core-asl 1.8.5 . Please suggest some solution for my problem.

```
  <properties>
      <jackson-lib.ver>1.8.5</jackson-lib.ver>
</properties>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-lib.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>${jackson-lib.ver}</version>
   </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the expected output :

```
 "atts": {
     "parent-id": "asd",
     "country-id": "sdfsafs"        
       }
```

This is my pojo :

```
public class Attr {

    @JsonProperty("parent-id")
    private String parentId;

    @JsonProperty("country-id")
    private String countryId;

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
    public String getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }
    public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

}
```

Now i am getting :

"atts": {
    "parentId": "asd",
    "countryId": "sdfsafs"
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are using the wrong version of annotations -- Maven group id must be same as for your mapper; `org.codehaus.jackson`. And not `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`, which is used by Jackson 2.x.